# Django Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I'm using Http file to make GET request using `rest_framework` Authentication

here is the command I use:

```
GET localhost:8000/api-admin/products
Authorization: Token 5e2cf6ddc7a0ff8fe03e4749d788a423f6640443
```

When I use the browser and go to that link it works successfully but when I use HTTP file or Postman I get `Authentication credentials were not provided.` error

Also I added the code in settings file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: have you added 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', in settings.py REST_FRAMEWORK

Comment: @NimishBansal yes I added it

Comment: may be you forgot to checked the box in postman Headers list

Comment: @bkawan its checked

Comment: It could be great if you could share screen of what and how you are doing. Since I have tested it and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I forgot to add `TokenAuthentication` in the `authentication_classes`

```
authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
```

inside the API file

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a trailing / at the end of the URL.